# Помогите отредактировать SQL-запрос

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть запрос выводящий все заказы. В таблице teh_otdel есть 6 отделов, и сейчас они все выводятся.

Я пытаюсь переделать запрос так, что бы в одном случае выводились все заказы связанные с этими 5 отделами, а в другом только с одним отделом. Но что то пока не выходит.

По ощущениям что то мелкое но проект достал уже голова не варит. Может кто подскажет что и как поменять.Буду премного благодарен если наставите на путь истинный.

```
SELECT 
    zkz_adr_inf.id, 
    zkz_adr_inf.date, 
    zkz_adr_inf.time, 
    zkz_adr_inf.metro, 
    zkz_adr_inf.sot_phone, 
    zkz_adr_inf.home_phone, 
    zkz_adr_inf.work_phone, 
    zkz_adr_inf.other_phone, 
    zkz_adr_inf.ulica, 
    teh_otdel.txt_otd, 
    zkz_tehnika.otdel, 
    zkz_tehnika.model, 
    user_info.f, 
    user_info.i, 
    ing_so, 
    teh_made.txt_made, 
    zkz_ispoln.status, 
    zkz_ispoln.etap, 
    zkz_ispoln.date_prisv, 
    zkz_ispoln.viez_ing, 
    zkz_ispoln.kur_in, 
    zkz_ispoln.ochered, 
    zkz_ispoln.menedg, 
    zkz_adr_inf.data_in, 
    zkz_adr_inf.time_in, 
    zkz_adr_inf.st, 
    text.txt as metro, 
    zkz_otmetki.last 
FROM 
    zkz_adr_inf 
LEFT JOIN zkz_ispoln 
    ON zkz_adr_inf.id = zkz_ispoln.id 
LEFT JOIN user_info 
    ON zkz_ispoln.menedg = user_info.id 
LEFT JOIN zkz_tehnika 
    ON zkz_adr_inf.id = zkz_tehnika.id 
LEFT JOIN teh_made 
    ON teh_made.id = zkz_tehnika.made 
LEFT JOIN teh_otdel 
    ON teh_otdel.id = zkz_tehnika.otdel 
RIGHT JOIN zkz_otmetki 
    ON zkz_otmetki.id = zkz_adr_inf.id 
LEFT JOIN text 
    ON text.id = zkz_adr_inf.metro 
WHERE 
    zkz_adr_inf.data_in BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '3000-01-01' 
ORDER BY 
    zkz_adr_inf.id DESC 
LIMIT 
    0, 30
```

Comment: Я думаю былобы лучше значение zkz_adr_inf.data_in сохранять в виде timestamp используя в php strtotime. Это будет работать намного быстрее.

Comment: @Hasanagha Aliyev гонево.

Comment: `WHERE teh_otdel.id = 1 /*1 отдел*/` и `WHERE teh_otdel.id IN (2,3,4,5,6) /*5 других отделов*/` . Но запрос с таким количеством джоинов - это треш.

Comment: `zkz_adr_inf.data_in BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '3000-01-01' ` шта?

Comment: к счастю писал не я мне что дали то и сказали допиливать (джойны фигня) вы просто не видели остальной код проекта (процедурка+ООПБ, переменный на транслите или вообще типа аа-бб-п3, хтл+цсс+пхп, что такоре пср? и т.д). Спасибо поробую  Гончаров Александр отпишусь как срабтало

Comment: типа фильтр времени у человека:))

Comment: Удалить базу, стереть ос, низкоуровневое форматирование дисков, продрелить дырочку в корпусе, налить кислоты. Пк/сервер сжечь. И написать заново. Это будет быстрее и профитнее.

Comment: @ASYOU А вопрос то в чем ? нужно отфильтровать по одному отделу, добавляете в where условие для этого. Если нужны 5 отделов из 6 то видимо условие типа `zkz_tehnika.otdel != X` (или перечисляете в IN все необходимые), а когда только 1 отдел то `zkz_tehnika.otdel = X`.

Comment: @Crystal А что в этом запросе вы увидели такое страшное ? всего то 7 таблиц ... Вопрос же только в грамотности индексов. и по 20 таблиц запросы отлично могут работать за доли секунды. Когда проблемы со скоростью тогда уже начинают думать о денормализации структуры и кешированию каких то данных, что бы сократить join

Comment: @Mike если Вам надо такое количество join'ов - значит стоит задуматься о том, что изначально данные структурированы не правильно. И речь даже не в том, сколько будет выполняться запрос. При должной оптимизации - не доли секунды, конечно, но секунды. Вопрос в логике данных.

Comment: @Crystal Я конечно не вижу тут полной модели и тем более не знаю предметную область, так что утверждать не могу. Но судя по названиям таблиц они представляют собой абсолютно разные сущности, а значит очень может быть, что данные с точки зрения НФ представлены абсолютно верно. Для увеличения быстродействия _может быть_ надо как то их денормализовать.